# Grouping duplicate values in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple object in the format of

```
class MyObject {
    public string foo;
    public string bar;
}
```

I have a list of these objects, where the value of 'foo' is unique, and the value of 'bar' is not. For example - Imagine the values were as follows

- Foo1, Bar1
- Foo2, Bar2
- Foo3, Bar1
- Foo4, Bar3

I'm looking to group up the items so they are as follows, a `Dictionary<string,List<string>` with unique 'bar' keys, and a `List<string>` of their associated 'foo' values.

- Bar1, [Foo1,Foo3]
- Bar2, [Foo2]
- Bar3, [Foo4]

I can do this using a fairly simple loop -

```
Dictionary<string,List<string>> result = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
myObjectList = new List<MyObject>();
foreach (MyObject obj in myObjectList)
{
    if (result.ContainsKey(obj.bar))
    {
        result[obj.bar].Add(obj.foo);
    } 
    else 
    {
        result.Add(obj.bar,new List<string> {obj.foo});
    }
}
```

But I'm trying to learn how to use LINQ correctly, and it seems like there would be an elegant solution using that. What would the correct way to do this using LINQ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you really just want a [`Lookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) via the [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup.aspx) method:

```
var lookup = myObjectList.ToLookup(x => x.bar, x => x.foo);
```

If you *really* need a `Dictionary` you could use something like:

```
var dictionary = myObjectList.GroupBy(x => x.bar, x => x.foo)
                             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

... but I'd use a lookup if you can.

Comment: Sorry could you explain why a lookup is good here? A lookup produces non-unique keys right? But the op wants unique keys...

Comment: Sorry ignore that. I understand your reasoning now :)

Comment: @Umair: A lookup still has unique keys, its just that they can map to multiple elements. To quote the lookup page: "A Lookup<TKey, TElement> resembles a Dictionary<TKey, TValue>. The difference is that a Dictionary<TKey, TValue> maps keys to single values, whereas a Lookup<TKey, TElement> maps keys to collections of values." In this case since a lookup already maps a key to a collection of values there is no need to use a Dictionary with TValue being some enumerable object.

Comment: Same as OP, I have an int in place of FOO and I need the sum of the int FOOs instead of Count; for all groups of Bars. Can you please tell me how can I do that. By doing something similar, I have a collection named 'elements' inside the var lookup (which has the individual int values), but i need their sum!!

Comment: @ViV: I suggest you post a new question, giving full details including what you've tried.